# C# StandardOutput hangs, how can I detect it's waiting for input?

Tags: c#, process, cmd

I have been working with processes (using the Process and ProcessStartInfo) with C# quite some time. Now, there is only one question that really bothered me and still haven't managed to find a way to work it out.

The StandardOutput will hang when the application is "waiting" for some input.
Which means, if you are using ReadToEnd it will never return (as the actual input window is invisible).

Now, this creates a problem when I'm using the StandardInput to provide the input. For example:

1. Starting the process with C#
2. Entering a command using StandardInput.
3. Start reading the stream for the ouptut.
4. Running another one based on the last output.

Now this is the problem: I can't tell whether the process is waiting for input or it's still generating one, as my process "gets" stuck to read from the StandardOutput (it's done on the same thread).

I need to read the output after my command ran, run some algorithms and then run another command based on the previous command output.

Is there is any way of detecting if the process running finished loading my command and waiting for new input? Just like the cmd does?

Answer (score 2):

Trying to follow Peter answer, I haven't found any special delimiter at the end of the StandardOutput (I checked the ErrorOutput as well).

Thinking of this through I thought, why not used echo to "simulate" a delimiter? So I put up this code which allows me to run a specific command and obtain the output immediately on the same thread:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// A string used to write into the bash and allows us to detect when the bash finished to write it's output.
    /// </summary>
    const string delimiterString = "#WAITING";

    /// <summary>
    /// Runs the specified command and return it's output.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="command"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string RunCommand(string command)
    {
        sessionProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(command);

        // Add a special string to be recognized when output is waiting
        sessionProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("echo \"" + delimiterString + "\"");

        string output = "";
        int lastChr = 0;

        do
        {
            lastChr = sessionProcess.StandardOutput.Read();

            string outputChr = null;
            outputChr += sessionProcess.StandardOutput.CurrentEncoding.GetString(new byte[] { (byte)lastChr });
            output += outputChr;

            if (output.EndsWith(delimiterString))
            {
                // Remove delimeter
                output = output.Replace(Environment.NewLine + delimiterString, "");
                output = output.Replace(delimiterString + Environment.NewLine, "");

                // Console.Write(output);
                break;
            }

        } while (lastChr > 0);

        return output;
    }
```

Comment: This is the only answer I could find that worked. Can't believe there is no way to do this with a built in feature. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there is any way of detecting if the process running finished loading my command and waiting for new input? Just like the cmd does?

Even cmd.exe doesn't really know whether the process has finished your command. It *does* know the process is waiting for input, but that's because it's responsible for providing the user interaction from which that input would be obtained. The process, even while waiting for input, could write more output at any time.

When redirecting I/O for a console process, you will have to detect the need to provide input the same way the user does: watch the output for a prompt.

It's impossible to provide specific advice, given that you posted no code, never mind [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. But in general, you should be able to just loop, reading lines from the output, and if and when you detect a prompt, then execute some code that will provide the appropriate response.

For example:

```
string line;
while ((line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
    if (line.EndsWith("Enter next command: "))
    {
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine("next command");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! the problem is that the last characer for the prompt is new line, which could be just a new line for the next output. So there is no really "special char" or string that will help me detect the prompt. Any ideas? This is kinda annoying since there is no really appropriate way of doing this.

Comment: The above code is just an example, and in fact _assumes_ that the last character for the prompt is a newline (i.e. the above loop won't even see the prompt until the line is terminated). You can use other `StreamReader` methods, such as `Read()` to retrieve all available character output as it appears, rather than waiting for a newline. One way or the other, there must be some kind of unique text recognizable as a prompt, otherwise how could a program or even a human user recognize it's time to provide more input? If you can provide a specific example, a more specific answer can be offered.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will update if I will have a good example

Comment: Ok I have checked it out. There is not special string, only 10 for new line. I read the StandardOutput and the StandardError. This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Very old question but I came up with a solution I want to share for those using >=.net5, I made a CLIService that works on a few assumptions that work for Powershell but could be updated to work with either a delimiter as mentioned above but this service will asynchronously return the result of a command using end of result delimiter like mentioned above and TaskCompletionSource to make async method that will return the whole result of a given command using the method `await CmdAsync("cmd")`, for regular commands use `Cmd("cmd")`.

NOTE: because im using PowerShell im delimiting `"PS "+Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` and sending an empty command after to an async command. you may need to update line 27 for what ever your empty command looks like

NOTE: this is nasty but im making an empty CmdAysnc call to make sure it runs all commands before i dispose, someone whos more experienced with Process could probably clean this up and make the Dispose() method handle it more gracefully.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class CLIService
    {
        private readonly Process _process;
        private string _output = "";
        private string _errors = "";
        private TaskCompletionSource<string> CommandTaskRes;
        private string awaitingCommand;
        private bool sendMessage = false;
        public string terminalLocation;
    
        public CLIService(string appExe = "powershell.exe") {
            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.FileName = appExe;
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo = psi;
            process.Start();
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            _process = process;

            string startInputString = "PS " + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

            process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
            {
                var msg = e.Data;
                Console.WriteLine(msg + Environment.NewLine); 
                //capture message in output to be sent back when completed
                if (sendMessage)
                {
                    //if returned to PS C:\\.., send output
                    if(msg.StartsWith(startInputString))
                    {
                        sendMessage = false;
                        CommandTaskRes.SetResult(_output);
                        _output = "";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _output += msg + Environment.NewLine;
                    }                    
                }
                else if (msg.StartsWith(startInputString) && msg.Split("> ")[1] == awaitingCommand)
                {
                    sendMessage = true;
                    awaitingCommand = null;
                }
            };
            

            process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
            {
                // Append the error to the error string
                _errors += e.Data + Environment.NewLine;
                throw new Exception(e.Data);
            };


            process.Exited += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (CommandTaskRes != null)
                {
                    CommandTaskRes.SetResult("");
                }
            };
        }

        //use this when you need the response of a command
        public async Task<string> CmdAsync(string cmd)
        {
            awaitingCommand = cmd;
            _process.StandardInput.WriteLine(cmd);
            //send empty to signify end of cmd to OutputDataReceived
            _process.StandardInput.WriteLine("");
            CommandTaskRes = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
            var res = await CommandTaskRes.Task;
            CommandTaskRes = null;
            return res;
          
        }

        // use this to run any other command where the result isnt needed
        public void Cmd(string cmd) {
            _process.StandardInput.WriteLine(cmd);
        }

        //run this to dispose after you run an empty CmdAsync or fix my nastiness 
        public void Dispose()
        {
            _process.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```