# How to identify if a Process needs input?

Tags: c#, process, system.diagnostics, redirectstandardoutput

I am running a command prompt utility using System.Diagnostics.Process class in .NET Framework. This command prompt utility might need some user input in some cases and also sometimes it finishes the task without needing any input from user.
Here is what I have done to run this process:

```
    var process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo([PATH_TO_EXE], arguments);
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.Start();
```

The problem is I don't know how to identify if this process needs input or not?

Comment: There's no way of knowing if the Process is *waiting for* input at any time. If you know how your specific process prompts the user for input you could read the StdOut and parse it though.

Comment: @NilsO: Thanks for your comment. I also tried to do exactly what you said. When I try to Read StandardOutput, the thread freezes and program hangs. Seems I cannot read output, while process is pending for input. Any idea?

Comment: what happens when you call `process.WaitForInputIdle();` before trying to write to StandardInput?

Comment: WaitForInputIdle failed.  This could be because the process does not have a graphical interface.

Comment: Why do you need to know if the process needs user input?

Comment: @ShellShock: I need to know if the process needs user input, because in that case I have to send a proper input to StandardInput in code.

Comment: Can't you just always send the "proper input"; if the process does not need it then it will be ignored?

Comment: @ShellShock: It's a good idea. Unfortunately the expected input is not a constant value and I need to check what exactly is needed as the input. So I cannot always write a constant input to the stream. :(

Comment: So how do you check what is needed as the input?

Comment: @ShellShock: If I could tell when an Input is needed, I would try to read StandardOutput lines, parse the output, prepare related input, and write them to StandardInput stream.

Comment: _"Seems I cannot read output, while process is pending for input"_ -- that's an entirely different issue, answered somewhat by the MSDN documentation for the Console class. The short version is that you need to process the input and output independently, or you need to use the output to detect when you've read all of the available output and it's time to send input again (as described in my answer in the duplicate question).

Comment: And here is the link to the duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29829028/3538012. Unfortunately, the OP of that question never really got a good handle on his own problem, but I hope that you'll find the discussion useful.

Comment: @themehrdad Did you ever figure out how to do this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @DonnyV. unfortunately not, we ended up solving our problem with a workaround. We used the application API instead. Meaning that we called the APIs that were exposed by the application that we were calling by command prompt.

Comment: @themehrdad This ended up working for me. Sending an echo command with a message right after. Just check for the echo message. When it pops up its done. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29937346/1231

Comment: That's great! would you like to write this as a reply so I can mark it as the solution? @DonnyV.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could find that worked. No matter how short or long the response was. Is too add an echo after you send a command like so. Than just check for the echo to know when to stop waiting.

```cs
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

process.StartInfo.FileName = Settings.MongoPath;

// Redirects the standard input so that commands can be sent to the shell.
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

process.StartInfo.Arguments = ConnString;

process.Start();

// this is key, this returns 1 once previous command in argument is done executing
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("{ping:1}");

var current_line = string.Empty;
var OutputList = new List<string>();
while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
{
    current_line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    if (current_line == "1")
    {
        // command is done executing 
        break;
    }

    OutputList.Add(current_line);
}

// contains all of the out put of the command
OutputList
```